# Navigate between screens in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a button that when clicked change to another screen in React Js but when I try to use it, it give me an errror: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. I don't know what else to do. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```js
import LinkForm from "./LinkForm";
import Links from "./Links";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const Link = (props) => {
  const addOrEditLink = async (linkObject) => {
    await db.collection("links").doc().set(linkObject);
    console.log("New Task Added");
  };
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
      <Router>
          <div>
        <LinkForm addOrEditLink={addOrEditLink} />
        <Route path='/links' component={Links}></Route>
        <button
            onClick={() => {
              props.history.push("/links");
            }}
        >
          Go Home
        </button>
      </div>
      </Router>
      
  );
};

export default withRouter(Link);
```

Comment: `const history`, it's available in the scope already, it's not in the `props`.

Comment: props.history.push("/links"); You're trying to push into history from props, but history doesn't exist on props. It is already present in the variable history.

Answer (score 1):

What do you have in props? Try just

```
onClick={() => {
              history.push("/links");
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<button
    onClick={() => {
        props.history.push("/links");
    }}>
    Go Home
</button>
```

To

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";


<Link to"/links">
    Go Home
</Link>
```